# Adding Multiple Image file to folder not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, pnp

I am using pnp for adding files but its just adding one file only.

I want to upload multiple Images files, and save it to the sharepoint folder.
Using React with Typescript.

```
<input type="file" name="Upload" onChange={(e) => this.handleFileChange(e.target.files)} multiple={true}/>
<button id="btn_add" className={styles.button} onClick={this.toUploadImages.bind(this)}>Submit</button>

private toUploadImages(): void {
let cWeb = new Web(this.props.endpointURL);
const uploadFiles = this.state.uploadFilesImage;
 try {
    pnp.sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("Images1")
    .files.add(uploadFiles.name, uploadFiles, true)
    .then((data)=> {
      console.log(data)
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
  };
public handleFileChange(selectorFiles: FileList) {
    this.setState({ uploadFilesImage: selectorFiles[0] });
  }
```

All I want to upload multiple files
Not sure why is this happening.... Can anyone help me with this...

Answer (score 0):

Demo based on previous project.

```
export interface IReactDropdownState {
  selectedItem?: { key: string | number | undefined };
  options: any[];
  modalIsOpen: boolean,
  pdfFile: FileList
}

handleChange(selectorFiles: FileList) {
    this.setState({ pdfFile: selectorFiles });
  }

Submit() {
    try {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.pdfFile.length; i++) {
        sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/lee/PublishingImages")
          .files.add(this.state.pdfFile[i].name, this.state.pdfFile[i], true)
          .then((data) => {
            console.log(data)
          })
      }
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }

<input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e.target.files)} multiple={true} />
            <button onClick={(e) => this.Submit()}>Submit</button>
```

Update(fileUploaded is the uploaded file list):

```
Submit() {
    try {
      var files = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < this.state.pdfFile.length; i++) {
        files.push(this.state.pdfFile[i]);
      }
      Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
        sp.web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl("/sites/lee/PublishingImages")
          .files.add(file.name, file, true)
      })).then((fileUploaded: any[]) => {
        fileUploaded.forEach((singleFile) => {
          console.log(singleFile);
        });
      });
    }
    catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
```

Comment: But I select many files, but it only upload one file

Comment: and what If I want to get the folder by id? Than add files?

Comment: The code had updated to upload multiple files, get folder by id, just replace getFolderByServerRelativeUrl as getFolderById

Comment: Can you help with like the many files I've uploaded after uploading is success I want to fetch all the files.

Comment: Check the Update.

Comment: When function is triggered the `console.log(singleFile);` says undefined. Perhaps file is getting upload.

Comment: debug it so you could get detailed error and help for troubleshooting.

Comment: The `singleFile` is coming undefined

Comment: Debug to confirm the fileUploaded at runtime, not console.log.

Comment: It has no vlaue assigned

Comment: Can't we push it in different state item?